# checking nested properties using Underscore has()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

How do you deal with this scenario?

```
_.has(item.attributes.format,'dateUpdated')
```

But you notice there are times that "format" doesn't exists too. Do you check it this way

```
if (_.has(item.attributes,'format')) {
  if (_.has(item.attributes.format,'dateUpdated')) {
    // ok, I'm sure it exists
  }
}
```

What is the ideal/professional/seasoned programmer way of checking it?

Comment: why not just if (obj.property && obj.property.nested) { ..code...}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest Lodash `has()` (https://lodash.com/docs#has) supports `a.b.c` format. You can use `_.has(item, 'attributes.format.dateUpdated')`.

Comment: That is awesome sweet! Thanks!